# Have Reputation Requirements for Privileges Changed?

Tags: support, moderation, help-center

Now that we're out of beta, it appears to me that the [reputation required](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) to reach various moderation and other milestone privileges has significantly increased. Am I missing something or am I on target with this one? It appears as though I've lost privileges now that we're out of beta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Once sites are out of beta the reputation to gain privileges rises to be consistent with the rest of the SE network.

So yes, you will have lost privileges (as will most people).

Comment: Looks like less people to do some of the moderation work for a while then until reps increase about 5 fold.

Comment: I think that during beta you only needed 50% of reputation of what's commonly required for site's out of beta. Can't find the source of that anymore though.

Comment: yep. one supposes that during it's infancy a SE does require a little more moderation?